# IntelliJ Idea closing automatically on maven build or application startup spring boot

Tags: windows, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, microservices

On application startup or maven clean, IntelliJ Idea is getting closed automatically.

```
 java.io.IOException: Failed to run C:\Windows\system32\wsl.exe --list --quiet: {exitCode=1, timeout=false, cancelled=false, stdout=
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Usage: wsl.exe [Argument]

Arguments:

--install <Options>
Install Windows Subsystem for Linux features. If no options are specified,
the recommended features will be installed along with the default distribution.

To view the default distribution as well as a list of other valid distributions,
use 'wsl --list --online'.

Options:
--distribution, -d [Argument]
Specifies the distribution to be downloaded and installed by name.

Arguments:
A valid distribution name (not case sensitive).

Examples:
wsl --install -d Ubuntu
wsl --install --distribution Debian

--list, -l [Options]
Lists distributions.

Options:
--online, -o
Displays a list of available distributions for install with 'wsl --install'.

--help
Display usage information.
, stderr=}
at com.intellij.execution.wsl.WslDistributionManagerImpl.doFetchDistributionsFromWslCli(WslDistributionManagerImpl.java:141)
at com.intellij.execution.wsl.WslDistributionManagerImpl.loadInstalledDistributionMsIds(WslDistributionManagerImpl.java:39)
at com.intellij.execution.wsl.WslDistributionManager.loadInstalledDistributions(WslDistributionManager.java:135)
at com.intellij.execution.wsl.WslDistributionManager.getInstalledDistributions(WslDistributionManager.java:61)
at git4idea.config.GitExecutableDetector.detectAvailableWsl(GitExecutableDetector.java:187)
at git4idea.config.GitExecutableDetector.runDetect(GitExecutableDetector.java:93)
at git4idea.config.GitExecutableDetector.lambda$detect$0(GitExecutableDetector.java:65)
at git4idea.config.GitExecutableManager.runUnderProgressIfNeeded(GitExecutableManager.java:238)
at git4idea.config.GitExecutableDetector.detect(GitExecutableDetector.java:62)
at git4idea.config.GitExecutableManager.getDetectedExecutable(GitExecutableManager.java:149)
at git4idea.config.GitExecutableManager.getPathToGit(GitExecutableManager.java:106)
at git4idea.config.GitExecutableManager.getPathToGit(GitExecutableManager.java:97)
at git4idea.config.GitExecutableManager.getExecutable(GitExecutableManager.java:112)
at git4idea.config.GitExecutableManager.testGitExecutableVersionValid(GitExecutableManager.java:280)
at git4idea.GitVcs.lambda$activate$0(GitVcs.java:209)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:183)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:705)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:647)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:63)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:170)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.BackgroundTaskUtil.lambda$execute$8(BackgroundTaskUtil.java:206)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1736)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Comment: The error you posted is hardlt related to the IDE crash. It just says that WSL distribution is not installed on you computer.

Comment: Try running the IDE from command line and share the generated output after the crash: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011901879-How-to-start-IDE-from-the-command-line

Comment: Also, share `java_error_in_*.log` files from the user profile (home) folder which should be generated after the crash.

Comment: Just figured out, Cylance security application is terminating IntelliJ in my system.

Comment: Updating Cylance security policy resolved the issue.

Comment: Resolved by updating Cylance security policy.